# Is there some kind of API for MSN protocol (for using in C# asp.net application)?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, msn

i was wandering, is there some kind of .NET API for MSN protocol, so I can make chat application which uses Windows Live Messenger data and servers.

If not than I will use .Net Sockets, TCP + UDP, but this is not very easy task, time consuming, and also ... you need strong server to support Chat Server (used to push and redirect messages to connected users)

Thanks all in advance,

Cheers!

Comment: Why not just use Windows Live Messenger?

Answer (score 1):

There is [MSNPSharp](https://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp), a third-party open source .NET wrapper for the MSN protocol written in C#.